# Read multiple input lines using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

I'm trying to do some algorithmic problems using Node's library of read lines : readline. (Actually, It was proposed by the course).

The input code was :

```
var readline = require('readline');
var lineNumber = 0;

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', readLine);

function readLine (line) {
    // Do some work here.
}
```

The problem is to calculate the sum of n numbers. As input we have : 
 1. In the first line, the number of numbers for which we want to calculate the sum.
 2. The second line will contain the "n" numbers seperated by spaces.

**An example for an input would be : 
5 
1 4 8 7 9 
The output in this case : 
25**

How can I do that with this library (I can do that with Java, C++, etc. But I don't know how to read multiple input lines using javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var readline = require('readline');
var lineNumber = 0;
var NumOfNum;

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', readLine);
console.log("Provide number of Numbers to sum:");
function readLine (line) {
    if (lineNumber == 0) {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(line))) {
            NumOfNum = parseInt(line);
            lineNumber++;
            console.log("Provide " + NumOfNum + " numbers sepearted by space to add: ");
        } else {
            console.log("Invalid Input");
        }
    } else {
        var sum = line.split(" ");
        if (sum.length != NumOfNum) {
            console.log("Given more/less than " + NumOfNum + " Try again");
        } else {
            sum = sum.reduce(function(a, b) {
              return (a*1) + (b*1);
            });
            console.log("Total: " + sum);
            process.exit();
        }
    }
}
```